# Scheme-theoretic segre embedding is a closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm doing some exercises in Hartshorne and need to construct the scheme-theoretic Segre embedding. I'm having trouble showing that it is closed immersion. Normally I would just go to the Stacks project when running up against a wall, but it seems that the  [proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WD) given there is incorrect since it gives the wrong ring homomorphism.

I understand that it suffices to prove this for projective space over $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $N = mn + n + m$, and let the coordinate ring for $\mathbb{P}^N$ be $\mathbb{Z}[\{z_{ij}\}]$ with $i \in \{0, \dots, m\}$ and $j\in \{0, \dots, n\}$.  Let $U_i$ and $U_j$ be the standard affine charts for $\mathbb{P}^m$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$, and let $U_{ij}$ denote the affine chart for $\mathbb{P}^N$ corresponding to the coordinate $z_{ij}$. I am under the impression that the Segre embedding is defined by gluing the maps on charts $U_{r} \times U_s \to U_{rs}$ defined by the ring homomorphisms $$\mathbb{Z}[\{z_{ij}/z_{rs}\}] \to \mathbb{Z}[x_0/x_r, \dots, x_m/x_r, y_0/y_s, \dots, y_n/y_s]$$
$$z_{ij}/z_{rs} \mapsto \frac{x_iy_j}{x_ry_s}$$
I also understand that the property of being a closed immersion is something that can be checked affine-locally, so it follows that the Segre embedding is a closed immersion if and only if the above map is a closed immersion of affine schemes, which is equivalent to the ring homomorphism being surjective.

However, it seems to me that this ring homomorphism is not surjective at all; any element of the form $x_r/x_i$ or $y_s/y_j$ seems to be excluded. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Can't you just take $j = s$ or $i = r$ respectively?